# MYSQL DATE_SUB not working correct in FEB

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this query and it is working fine, except in the month of FEB! for some reason because FEB has 28 days by using the `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` function it reads back into JAN also. and it should only read from start of FEB to END of FEB!

```
SELECT SUM(IF((`date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2013-02-28', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND '2013-02-28'), earnings, "null")) AS Rev0 
FROM table
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? is it to get if the 'date' is in february or something? You have me confused here.

Comment: it is a dynamic query. it just gets the current months total "earnings" in that table "fake table name i used here". With the information I am populating a chart, but it is getting data from 30 Jan 2013 up to 28 Feb 2013, and it should only get information from 01 Feb 2013 to 28 Feb 2013. PS the complete query is a bit more complicated as it gets data for 6 months and creates 5 more columns similar to this 'Rev0' column.

Comment: sorry reads from 28 Jan 2013 not 30 Jan 2013.

Comment: @SchalkKeun if you are passing in dates to the query why not just pass in the first and last day of month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any date, you can use this to get the first day of the month:

```
DATE_SUB('2013-02-28', INTERVAL DAY('2013-02-28')-1 DAY)
```

or also this:

```
CAST(DATE_FORMAT('2013-02-28' ,'%Y-%m-01') as DATE)
```

and for the last day, there's a function already defined:

```
LAST_DAY('2013-02-28')
```

your query would then become:

```
SELECT
  SUM(IF((`date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2013-02-28', INTERVAL DAY('2013-02-28')-1 DAY)
          AND LAST_DAY('2013-02-28')), earnings, "null")) AS Rev0 
FROM table
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(IF((date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB('2013-02-28', INTERVAL 1 MONTH),"%Y-%m-01") AND LAST_DAY('2013-02-28')), ROUND(earnings,2), "null")) as Rev0 FROM table;`

thanks for the 'LAST_DAY' it opened up my mind. was part of my solution.